# Why couldn't I access the static field in enum in constructor?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot access static field within enum initialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278432/cannot-access-static-field-within-enum-initialiser)

My situation:

```
enum Attribute { POSITIVE, NEGATIVE }
enum Content {
    C1(Attribute.POSITIVE),
    C2(Attribute.POSITIVE),
    ... // some other positive enum instances.
    Cm(Attribute.NEGATIVE),
    ... // some other negative enum instances.
    Cn(Attribute.NEGATIVE);

    private final Atrribute a;
    static int negativeOffset = 0;
    private Content(Atrribute a) {
        this.a = a;
        if ( a.compareTo(Attribute.POSITIVE) == 0 ) {
               negativeOffset ++;
        }
    }

    public static int getNegativeOffset() { return negativeOffset; }
}
```

My intention is to add negativeOffset by one whenever I add a new enum(with POSITIVE attribute), then I could  call the getNegativeOffset() to get the start point of  negative
enum and do whatever  I want.

But comlier complains that

`Cannot refer to the static enum field Content.negativeOffset within an initializer`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536449/cannot-refer-to-the-static-enum-field-within-an-initializer

This will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this "trick":

```
private static class IntHolder {
    static int negativeOffset;
}
```

then refer to the variable like this:

```
IntHolder.negativeOffset ++;
```

and

```
return IntHolder.negativeOffset;
```

The reason this works is that the JVM guarantees that the variable is initialized when the `IntHolder` static inner class is initialized, which doesn't happen until it's accessed.

The whole class will then be as follows, which compiles:

```
enum Attribute { POSITIVE, NEGATIVE }
enum Content {
    C1(Attribute.POSITIVE),
    C2(Attribute.POSITIVE),
    ... // some other positive enum instances.
    Cm(Attribute.NEGATIVE),
    ... // some other negative enum instances.
    Cn(Attribute.NEGATIVE);

    private final Attribute a;

    private static class IntHolder {
        static int negativeOffset;
    }

    private Content(Attribute a) {
        this.a = a;
        if ( a == Attribute.POSITIVE) {
               IntHolder.negativeOffset ++;
        }
    }

    public static int getNegativeOffset() { return IntHolder.negativeOffset; }
}
```

Note the corrections for spelling errors and the simpler comparison with the `Attribute` enum value using `==` instead of `compareTo()`

Comment: Thanks, nice tricks ! I didn't expect that this thread-safety trick also works here ! BTW, I still wonder why the original method won't work. Doesn't static fileld initialization happen before constructor?

Comment: Your problem was that enums can't have any declarations before the instances, which means that you can't initialise (or use) any static fields that the constructor of instances need. However, by putting the field inside *another* class, albeit an inner static one, the other class gets loaded (and statically initialized) on first usage, which is in the constructor. This pattern is an awesome way to thread-safely lazy initialize a singleton *without* any synchronization.